# Linux: How do you pass a file list to a linux command?

Tags: linux, windows, shell

I made a very small c++ application that creates a script that makes the shell script but is there an easier way do to it in the shell?  In Windows, I would just drag and drop the file list into a .bat file. 
I want do it something like pass the file list to a linux app multiple times as an automation.  Why?  I want to convert my MP3 files to M4A files using ffmpeg.

Comment: You would typically use a for loop (or just a glob, if the program supports it). Do you have an example of the command you want to run for each file?

Answer (score 1):

try something similar to:

```
ls *.mp3 | xargs -n 1 -I {} ffmpeg -i {} -c:a libfaac -vn $(basename {} .mp3).m4a
```

PS i didn't test it, so you might have to debug it...

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can go about this, for one you can put your file list in a separate file and then pass that file in as input to your script like so:

```
cat filelist.txt | bash yourScript.sh
```

Granted you have to be able to handle the input of the list in your script yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I had a problem with my account.  So I had to make another one.  It is sensitive.  Thank you for the xargs solution. 
This code is buggy but it makes a text file for processing commands like a big batch file with a shell command.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string hello;
string hello2;
string one; 
string two;
string dummy;
ifstream fp;
ofstream fp2;
//FILE *fp;
//read file until done
//cout<<"Okay I'm creating a list."<<endl;
system("clear ; ls > stuff.txt");
//cout<<"reporting it back..."<<endl;
//system("cat stuff.txt");
//fp = fopen("stuff.txt","r");
fp.open("stuff.txt");
fp2.open("robot.sh");
if (!fp && !fp2)
    exit(1);

while(fp)
{
hello = "command -i";
fp>>hello;
//a messy way to get the last line 
fp2<<"command -i"<<hello<<" -more commands "<<hello<<".ext"<<endl;
cout<<"command -i"<<hello<<" -more commands "<<hello<<".ext"<<endl;
}
fp.close();
fp2.close();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(I didn't test this)
Make a shell script that uses one parameter for the inputfile.
In that script always double-quote the variable (spaces!)

Configure Windows so that it will show up in your right mouseclick context menu from explorer or even configure your script to open all MP3 files.